# PyQt5 sending a signal to QMediaPlayer

Tags: python, python-3.x, video, pyqt5

Teaching myself PyQt5, I wanted to write a program that plays a video link found on a website. Since QT Designer didn't have a video widget, I had to find my own that someone else had written, and imported it into my program. The entire code that I'm importing can be found [HERE](http://pastebin.com/xKXkMYFQ). This video widget window is a 2nd window that opens after the video is selected.

What I'm trying to do is change the video window's title when the playlist's index changes. Seems I should be able to do this with: `self.playlist.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.dialog.setWindowTitle('Changed!'))` but the problem I'm having is since I'm importing the class/code that opens the video widget, I can't figure out how to watch for the signal.

Here's my function:

```
def play_all_replays(self):
        """
        creates a QMediaPlaylist object and inserts all the games replays (in order) to the playlist
        and then plays it.
        :return:
        """
        self.dialog = videowidget.VideoPlayer()  # this is the video player widget I import
        self.playlist = QMediaPlaylist()  # the playlist
        self.dialog.mediaPlayer.setPlaylist(self.playlist)  #mediaplay is the QMediaPlayer created in videowidget()
        for v in self.single_game_highlights_ordered:
            url = QUrl(v)
            self.playlist.addMedia(QMediaContent(url))
        self.dialog.mediaPlayer.setPlaylist(self.playlist)

        self.playlist.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.dialog.mediaPlayer.play()
        self.dialog.setWindowTitle('MLB Replay - {}')
        self.dialog.show()
        self.playlist.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.dialog.setWindowTitle('Changed!'))
```

So I'm kind of lost here. How do I watch for this signal change, and then pass it over to the video widget I've imported so I can change the window title (or other things, like I want to enable the "next" button if it's a playlist, or the "previous" button after the first video in the playlist has played)?

Comment: Doh, and I think I figured it out. I can't use `self.dialog.setWindowTitle('Changed!')` with `self.playlist.currentIndexChanged.connect`. Instead I needed to create a function to handle the signal (like I did with every other signal in my program) And put the `setWindowTitle` in there. Doing that, it works. Tired eyes and brain I guess.

Comment: Or: `connect(lambda: self.dialog.setWindowTitle('Changed!'))`

Comment: Since you've solved the problem yourself, please consider deleting your question. If you think future readers can benefit from it, then please add an answer of your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution. Change the last line of the function to:

```
self.playlist.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.playlist_changed)
```

Which then calls this function:

```
def playlist_changed(self):
        num = self.playlist.currentIndex()  # gets current playlist index
        self.dialog.setWindowTitle('MLB Replay - {}'.format(self.replay_window.item(num).text()))
```